# LINQ to SQL - OR/AND multiple values

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following scenario:

One search box that can search based on 3 different conditions in one of my tables (OR)
Contiditon 1) Name + MiddleName + LastName (all three are different table columns)
Contiditon 2) LegalName (another column)
Contiditon 3) Document (another column)

I'm trying to use LINQ to create a query that can get the results searching each field separatedely, but i'm having problems on multiple search terms scenario.

Says someone searches for "foo bar". I want the query to return anyone that has foo AND bar (in any order) contained in conditions 1, 2 or 3
I think this would be easy if the first condition weren't 3 separate fields concatenated, but that's not the case.

so far I have this:

```
var searchTerms = "foo bar";
foreach (var splitValue in searchTerms.Split(' '))
{
    var val = splitValue;
    query =
        query.Where(
            p =>
                   (p.Name + (p.MiddleName != null ? " " + p.MiddleName : string.Empty) + 
                   (p.LastName != null ? " " + p.LastName : string.Empty)).Contains(val)
                || (p.LegalName ?? string.Empty).Contains(val)
                || (p.Document ?? string.Empty).Contains(val));
}
```

This would return me results that containd foo and bar in any of the 3 conditions, but instead I want results that contains foo an bar in at least one of the conditions.

Do you think it's possible to write the query I desire in LINQ ?

Comment: It is, however, you might need to create a useful tool in a form of an extension method to do that.

Comment: @AgentFire I don't think that creating an extension would be a problem, the thing is I couldn't come up with a solution even using a separate method. Maybe someone will come up with some idea that can guide me closer to a solution. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reversing your loops like this

```
    query.Where(p => splitValue.All(val =>  (p.Name + (p.MiddleName != null ? " " + p.MiddleName : string.Empty) + 
               (p.LastName != null ? " " + p.LastName : string.Empty)).Contains(val)
            || (p.LegalName ?? string.Empty).Contains(val)
            || (p.Document ?? string.Empty).Contains(val)));
```

not sure about the performance though. Als an alternative you could do the query for each search term and then take the intersection of them